# How EAR packages and beans can share session id?

Tags: java, jboss, ear, war

I have 3 EAR packages which combined together makes one huge web java application. Is it possible to configure the beans into the packages to share the session id data between them. My idea is to develop a login form which registers users into database tables using session id. Every time then users browse the application their session id is used to identify the users. The tricky part comes when users switch between different EAR packages and beans. The session id will change and other beans won't know what is the new session id. Is there a way to configure the beans into the EAR packages to share the data which contains the session id.

---

I created two identical EAR packages and I placed context.xml file in each one. This is the file structure:

```
SR_57
├── pom.xml
├── SR_57-ear
│   ├── pom.xml
│   ├── src
│   │   └── main
│   │       └── application
│   │           └── META-INF
│   │               └── MANIFEST.MF
│   └── target
│       ├── application.xml
│       ├── maven-archiver
│       │   └── pom.properties
│       ├── SR_57-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT
│       │   ├── META-INF
│       │   │   ├── application.xml
│       │   │   └── MANIFEST.MF
│       │   ├── SR_57-ejb-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
│       │   └── SR_57-web-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war
│       └── SR_57-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT.ear
├── SR_57-ejb
│   ├── pom.xml
│   ├── src
│   │   ├── main
│   │   │   ├── java
│   │   │   │   └── com
│   │   │   │       └── SR_57
│   │   │   └── resources
│   │   │       └── META-INF
│   │   │           └── MANIFEST.MF
│   │   └── test
│   │       └── java
│   │           └── com
│   │               └── SR_57
│   └── target
│       ├── classes
│       │   └── META-INF
│       │       └── MANIFEST.MF
│       ├── endorsed
│       │   └── javaee-endorsed-api-6.0.jar
│       ├── maven-archiver
│       │   └── pom.properties
│       ├── SR_57-ejb-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
│       └── surefire
└── SR_57-web
    ├── faces-config.NavData
    ├── nb-configuration.xml
    ├── pom.xml
    ├── src
    │   ├── main
    │   │   ├── java
    │   │   │   └── com
    │   │   │       └── SR_57
    │   │   │           └── userCheck.java
    │   │   ├── resources
    │   │   └── webapp
    │   │       ├── home.xhtml
    │   │       ├── index.html
    │   │       ├── resources
    │   │       │   ├── css
    │   │       │   │   ├── sr_style.css
    │   │       │   │   └── style.css
    │   │       │   ├── images
    │   │       │   │   ├── 1.jpg
    │   │       │   │   ├── 2.jpg
    │   │       │   │   ├── 3.jpg
    │   │       │   │   ├── 4.jpg
    │   │       │   │   ├── 5.jpg
    │   │       │   │   ├── 6.jpg
    │   │       │   │   ├── 7.jpg
    │   │       │   │   ├── bg_1.jpg
    │   │       │   │   ├── bg.jpg
    │   │       │   │   ├── overlay_1.png
    │   │       │   │   ├── overlay.png
    │   │       │   │   ├── title_1.png
    │   │       │   │   └── title.png
    │   │       │   └── js
    │   │       │       ├── ChunkFive_400.font.js
    │   │       │       ├── cufon-yui.js
    │   │       │       ├── jquery.easing.1.3.js
    │   │       │       └── jquery.min.js
    │   │       ├── userNav.xhtml
    │   │       └── WEB-INF
    │   │           ├── context.xml
    │   │           ├── faces-config.xml
    │   │           ├── java.sql.Driver
    │   │           └── web.xml
    │   └── test
    │       └── java
    │           └── com
    │               └── SR_57
    └── target
        ├── classes
        │   └── com
        │       └── SR_57
        │           └── userCheck.class
        ├── endorsed
        │   └── javaee-endorsed-api-6.0.jar
        ├── generated-sources
        │   └── annotations
        ├── maven-archiver
        │   └── pom.properties
        ├── SR_57-web-1.0-SNAPSHOT
        │   ├── home.xhtml
        │   ├── index.html
        │   ├── META-INF
        │   ├── resources
        │   │   ├── css
        │   │   │   ├── sr_style.css
        │   │   │   └── style.css
        │   │   ├── images
        │   │   │   ├── 1.jpg
        │   │   │   ├── 2.jpg
        │   │   │   ├── 3.jpg
        │   │   │   ├── 4.jpg
        │   │   │   ├── 5.jpg
        │   │   │   ├── 6.jpg
        │   │   │   ├── 7.jpg
        │   │   │   ├── bg_1.jpg
        │   │   │   ├── bg.jpg
        │   │   │   ├── overlay_1.png
        │   │   │   ├── overlay.png
        │   │   │   ├── title_1.png
        │   │   │   └── title.png
        │   │   └── js
        │   │       ├── ChunkFive_400.font.js
        │   │       ├── cufon-yui.js
        │   │       ├── jquery.easing.1.3.js
        │   │       └── jquery.min.js
        │   ├── userNav.xhtml
        │   └── WEB-INF
        │       ├── classes
        │       │   └── com
        │       │       └── SR_57
        │       │           └── userCheck.class
        │       ├── context.xml
        │       ├── faces-config.xml
        │       └── web.xml
        ├── SR_57-web-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war
        └── surefire

64 directories, 75 files
```

I placed the context.xml file into WEB-INF directory and I added this line:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SessionCookie path="/" />
```

I added a java code which takes from the beans the cookie number and writes them into database. Then I run bought EAR packages to see are they going to share one session id. It turns out that that the cookie id from one client with one browser is different. The configuration is not working. I use JBoss 7.1.0

Maybe I have mistaken the directory where I have to place the context.xml file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the proper way is to go for Single Sign On options. There are few open source projects available like JOSSO, OpenSSO etc.

Comment: I know this post is older, now its possible in jboss with minimum config. link http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/wildfly-8/sharing-httpsession-between-web-applications-in-an-ear

Answer (score 1):

Session cookies are by default tied to the context path. You'd like to tie them to the domain root instead (assuming that all webapps runs on the same domain) so that the browser will return the same session cookie back to all webapp contexts running in the same domain. You could do it by either a custom cookie which is tied to the domain instead of the context path by setting the cookie's path accordingly:

```
Cookie cookie = new Cookie(name, value);
cookie.setPath("/");
```

or by configuring the servlet container to tie the default session cookie to the domain instead of the context path. In case of JBoss, check the `<SessionCookie>` setting in `context.xml`:

```
<SessionCookie path="/" />
```

Comment: I use Jboss 7. Is it going to work if I add this "<SessionCookie path="/opt/SessionCookie/" />" in every .EAR's web.xml file?

Comment: The session cookie will only be sent on every request which matches the specified path (and thus not on requests which does not match the specified path). If that is exactly what you want, go ahead.